# Is there a word for the front seats in a car?

Tags: word-request

Is there a word for the front seats in a car? I can think of "the driver's seat" for the driver's seat, and "first row of the car" to refer to the front seats, but it's an awkward phrase, so I am wondering if there are better alternatives. I can't really think of one.

Comment: "Front seats" is the term. There's no other that I've ever heard of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, from MW,

> [**passenger seat**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/passenger%20seat)
>
> > the front seat of a vehicle (such as a car) where a passenger sits

While passengers could also sit in the back seats, if you use the term "passenger seat" it (at least in the US) it always means the front seat that is not the drivers seat. So much so that the sides of a car are called "drivers side" and "passenger side".

Comment: Passenger Seat usage is the same in the UK, although sometimes I hear the terminology of near-side and off-side, but they are usually only used in official capacities such as accident reports. We also sometimes say *ride up/in front* to mean in one of the front seats (sometimes there are 2 passenger seats or a front seat-bench in vans etc)

Answer (score 1):

Riding shotgun. People used to say "I'm riding shotgun." It means "I'm going to sit in the front next to driver."

> #### Ride shotgun
>
> 1.1 Ride in the front passenger seat of a vehicle.
>
> ‘Jacob got in the back seat next to Katie and Jessica rode shotgun’
>
> [[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/ride_shotgun)]